# image not displaying in PDF template using Spring Boot, flying saucer and Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I create a file pdf from html template using Spring Boot, flying saucer, thymeleaf. But image is not displaying in my file.

**Project structure:**

[image: Project structure]

**code html:**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 invoice-col-2">
   <img src="../static/images/mastercard.png" alt="mastercard"></img>
</div>
```

When I change img tag to:

```
<img src="../static/images/mastercard.png" alt="mastercard" th:src="@{static/images/mastercard.png}"></img>
```

When I create PDF file, I get an error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "static/images/mastercard.png" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (context is of class: org.thymeleaf.context.Context)

Comment: Try with absolute path or make `src="/images/mastercard.png" ` in `img`tag

Comment: thanks for response. I try change src="/images/mastercard.png" in img tag but image not display. I use <img src="http://example.com/images/mastercard.png" alt="mastercard"></img> in img tag and it display. I've just done it. :))

Comment: can you please see my post i have a probleme with classpath Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355363/lambda-spring-boot-converting-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 18):

Try using Spring's `classpath:` prefix. This loads your file directly from the classpath, no matter if you are running from a `.jar` or within your IDE. Here is an example:

```
<img alt="mastercard" th:src="@{classpath:static/images/mastercard.png}" />
```

More information about `classpath:` can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-resourceloader).

Comment: After a few hours of searching and trying different things, this solution worked for me

Answer (score 4):

In order to embed an image in a PDF generated by Flying Saucer,

1)  Convert the image to a base64 encoded string.

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static/images/mastercard.png");
String base64Image = convertToBase64(path);
```

Function to convert image stored in a path like shown above, to a base64 encoded string

```
private String convertToBase64(Path path) {
    byte[] imageAsBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
      Resource resource = new UrlResource(path.toUri());
      InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
      imageAsBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("\n File read Exception");
    }

    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageAsBytes);
  }
```

2) Set the base64 encoded image in the thymeleaf context

```
    Context context = new Context();
    String image = "data:image/png;base64, " + base64Image;
    context.setVariable("image",  image);

    String html = templateEngine.process("template", context);
```

3) In HTML, set the value of image as shown below:

```
<img th:src="${image}" style="width: 200px; height=100px"/>
```

4) Finally, render the HTML template to PDF

```
  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
  renderer.setDocumentFromString(html); // html -> String created in Step 2
  renderer.layout();
  final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  renderer.createPDF(baos)
```

Now you have the byteArrayOutputStream of the generated PDF, with which you can choose to store them to a file server or serve it to a client in a format of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use standard html src atribute and relative path from root of the project.

You can put your image in the root of the project and use it like this:

```
<img src="mastercard.png" />
```

If you want to resource folders you can set it like this:

```
<img src="src/main/resources/static/images/mastercard.png" />
```

Comment: full path is working for me. I used for css link. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="src/main/resources/static/css/pdfexport.css"/>

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but reading image file from disk is little costly, I would suggest you go with uri-data

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-data-urls-for-embedding-images-in-flying-saucer-generated-pdfs/

Because you anyway going to read image to generate PDF, better keep it in template.

Comment: still valuable, ty

Answer (score 0):

@sangeethapradeep's answer almost worked for me with the exception that I need to convert svg image to base64. So I used https://pixelied.com/convert/svg-converter/svg-to-base64 to convert my image and included in the code and it worked.