# Loading static resources when generating a pdf with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, css, spring, pdf, thymeleaf

I'm trying to generate a pdf using thymeleaf but the problem is that when generating the pdf, the static resources such as css and js are not being loaded. If I render the html as a web page the resources are loaded perfectly but whenever I generate the pdf the resources are not applied. Does anyone knows if there is a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to fix the import of static content but here I found a workaround to add images: [image not displaying in PDF template using Spring Boot, flying saucer and Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418212/image-not-displaying-in-pdf-template-using-spring-boot-flying-saucer-and-thymel)