# logo is not displayed in thymleaf html template especially while downloading the pdf file

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymleaf html template for generating pdf using java in spring boot. The logo and image are not loading. It throws an error. Refer to the code and error attached below.

**Note:** But the image is loading for preview and print interface. For download alone, I am facing a problem.
**File location:**
user:/src/main/resources/static/images$ ls
logo.png  user-image-2.jpg

// code

```
<div class="logo">
   <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}" />
</div> 
   <img class="profilepic" th:src="@{/images/user-image-2.jpg}">
```

// code for generating pdf

```
 public File generatePdf(String id) throws Exception {
        Context context = initProfileContext(id);
        String html = loadAndFillTemplate(context);
        return renderPdf(id, html);
    }

    private File renderPdf(String id, String html) throws Exception {
        File file = File.createTempFile("profile_" + id, ".pdf");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer(20f * 4f / 3f, 20);
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        file.deleteOnExit();
        return file;
    }

    private Context initProfileContext(String id) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("profile", profileService.findById(id));
        return context;
    }

    private String loadAndFillTemplate(Context context) {
        return templateEngine.process("profile", context);
    }
```

// error

```
2020-10-29 16:53:13.799 ERROR 26176 --- [nio-5555-exec-2] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-5555-exec-2] Exception processing template "profile": Link base "/images/logo.png" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "profile" - line 66, col 6)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/images/logo.png" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "profile" - line 66, col 6)
        at org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder.computeContextPath(StandardLinkBuilder.java:493) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder.buildLink(StandardLinkBuilder.java:126) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.context.AbstractEngineContext.buildLink(AbstractEngineContext.java:167) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.LinkExpression.executeLinkExpression(LinkExpression.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:85) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:592) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at com.palmtree.matrimony.service.ProfilePdfService.loadAndFillTemplate(ProfilePdfService.java:50) ~[main/:na]
        at com.palmtree.matrimony.service.ProfilePdfService.generatePdf(ProfilePdfService.java:27) ~[main/:na]
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/images/logo.png" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "profile" - line 66, col 6)
        at org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder.computeContextPath(StandardLinkBuilder.java:493)
        at com.palmtree.matrimony.controller.ProfileController.download(ProfileController.java:93) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9
```

Comment: Can you add more code on how you are creating the PDF?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Updated the question. Refer above for code to generate pdf. I took reference from this github link https://github.com/gustavoponce7/pdfgenerator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gpch/pdfgenerator/service/PdfService.java

Comment: @selvi - If one of the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698004/validate-a-state-via-its-pincode-in-java/) resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Comment: can you please se my question it doesn't work for me Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355363/lambda-spring-boot-converting-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Springboot classpath prefix.

example:

```
<img class="profilepic" th:src="@{classpath:images/user-image-2.jpg}">
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907375/3427462