# Validate a state via its pincode in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to generate regex to validate state as Tamilnadu based on Pincode validation

Regex which I tried fails at some point

```
String regex = "^[60-64]{2}{0-9}{4}$";
```

Ref the Tamil Nadu Pincode info [link](https://chennaiiq.com/india/pincode/?id=31). It starts with 60-64 as the first two digits, the next 4 digits as 0-9 numbers. It must have six digits.

the code

```
public boolean isHomeState(String state, String zipcode) {
    if (isValidZipCode(zipcode)) { 
    // ...
    }
    return true;  
}

private boolean isValidZipCode(String zipcode) {
    String regex = "^[60-64]{2}{0-9}{4}$";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    // If the pin code is empty
    // return false
    if (zipcode == null) {
        return false;
    }

    Matcher m = p.matcher(zipcode);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: " fails at some point " - Can you give more details?

Comment: A [mcve] with inputs and expected output would help. Without the need to reference an external link that just has a long list, with no explanation.

Comment: Your regex says `[60-64]`. A regular expression is character based, it doesn't know numbers. That means this is treated as a group of 6, 0 to 6, and 4, i.e., 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4. You want `6[0-4]` as @Abra wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("6[0-4]\\d{4}");
```

In other words, the digit `6` followed by a digit that is either `0` or `1` or `2` or `3` or `4` and ending with exactly four digits.

Answer (score 0):

There are many regex patterns to do it e.g.

1. `6[0-4][0-9]{4}` which means `6` followed by a digit in the range, `0` to `4` which in turn followed by exactly 4 digits.
2. `6[0-4]\d{4}` which means `6` followed by a digit in the range, `0` to `4` which in turn followed by exactly 4 digits
3. `6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` which means `6` followed by a digit in the range, `0` to `4` which in turn followed by exactly 4 digits

However, let's analyze your regex, `[60-64]{2}[0-9]{4}` which will help you understand the problem better.

The regex, `[60-64]` means **only one** of the following:

1. 6
2. A digit in the range `0` to `6`
3. 4

And `[60-64]{2}` means the above repeated exactly two times i.e. it will match with a combination of 2 digits in the range, `0` to `6` e.g. `00`, `60`, `34`, `01`, `10`, `11` etc.

As a result, the regex, `[60-64]{2}[0-9]{4}` will match with first 2 digits consisting of digits in the range, `0` to `6` and next 4 digits consisting of digits in the range, `0` to `9` e.g.

```
012345
123856
234569
101010
202020
303030
404040
505050
606060
111111
222222
333333
```

which is not something you expect.